# How to pass the 'argument-line' of one PowerShell function to another?

Tags: powershell, metaprogramming, splat

I'm trying to write some PowerShell functions that do some stuff and then transparently call through to existing built-in functions.  I want to pass along all the arguments untouched.  I don't want to have to know any details of the arguments.

I tired using 'splat' to do this with `@args` but that didn't work as I expected.

In the example below, I've written a toy function called `myls` which supposed to print *hello!* and then call the same built-in function, `Get-ChildItem`, that the built-in alias `ls` calls with the rest of the argument line intact.  What I have so far works pretty well:

```
function myls
{
  Write-Output "hello!"
# $MyInvocation | Format-List          # <-- uncomment this line for debug info
  Invoke-Expression ("Get-ChildItem " + $MyInvocation.UnboundArguments -join " ")
}
```

A correct version of `myls` should be able to handle being called with no arguments, with one argument, with named arguments, from a line containing multiple semi-colon delimited commands, and with variables in the arguments including string variables containing spaces.  Basically, it should be a drop-in alternative to `ls`.

The tests below compare `myls` and the builtin `ls`:

*[NOTE: output elided and/or compacted to save space]*

```
PS> md C:\p\d\x, C:\p\d\y, C:\p\d\"jay z"
PS> cd C:\p\d
PS> ls                                 # no args
PS> myls                               # pass
PS> cd ..
PS> ls d                               # one arg
PS> myls d                             # pass
PS> $a="A"; $z="Z"; $y="y"; $jz="jay z"
PS> $a; ls d; $z                       # multiple statements
PS> $a; myls d; $z                     # pass
PS> $a; ls d -Exclude x; $z            # named args
PS> $a; myls d -Exclude x; $z          # pass
PS> $a; ls d -Exclude $y; $z           # variables in arg-line
PS> $a; myls d -Exclude $y; $z         # pass
PS> $a; ls d -Exclude $jz; $z          # variables containing spaces in arg-line
PS> $a; myls d -Exclude $jz; $z        # FAIL!
```

Is there a way I can re-write `myls` to get the behavior I want?

**Short answer:** Yes, it's possible.  The bad news: it requires code which knows details of the parameters and other metadata about the function one wishes to call through to.  The good news: *one doesn't need to write this all oneself*.  This metadata is available programatically and there exist modules available which one can use to auto-generate skeleton proxy code (see @Jaykul's answer below). I choose to use [the module named "MetaProgramming"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/01/04/extending-and-or-modifing-commands-with-proxies.aspx).  Once imported, generating a drop-in `myls` script is dead simple:

`New-ProxyCommand ls > .\myls.ps1`

Then one can start customizing the newly-generated `myls.ps1` script, like this:

```
  ...
  begin
  {
    Write-Output "hello!"              # <-- add this line
    try {
      $outBuffer = $null
  ...
```

Voila!  This new version passes all the tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a drop-in wrapper for ls, you should write a [proper Proxy Command](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/extending-andor-modifing-commands-with-proxies/).  There are a couple of versions of the generator on PoshCode.org, including [the one from Lee Holmes' PowerShell Cookbook](https://poshcode.org/scripts/2197),

But the proxy command generator is built in now, so you can just write:

```
$CommandName = "Get-ChildItem"
$Command = Get-Command $CommandName
[System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::Create($Command)
```

Comment: In other words: automated copy-pasting. Just astounding.

Comment: If you could copy-paste, you wouldn't need code-generation.  What the OP is doing is trying to subclass the command: writing a new command based on the original, but with custom modifications ... and in script. If you were doing it in C#, you'd just inherit. But you're in PowerShell, so you have to write a function which starts by duplicating the set of parameters from the original cmdlet (in PowerShell, we call those proxy functions).  If there was ever anything that cried for code-generation, this is it.

Answer (score 4):

Making a wrapper properly is not that easy, unfortunately. First of all, the splat operator should presumably be applied to a hashtable (e.g. automatic `PSBoundParameters` or another), not to the array `$args` directly.

There are at least two options (both are not perfect), and a hack (see the update section).

Option 1. Use the "classic" way of making a wrapper. Example: see how this is done for the function `help` which is a wrapper of the `Get-Help` cmdlet:

```
Get-Content function:\help
```

You can see that the wrapper function declarers **all** the parameters that the wrapped cmdlet has in order to have that `PSBoundParameters` **bounded to the existing function parameters**.

Your example. If your function declares the parameter `Exclude` then the example code starts to work. But it works for `Exclude` only, not `Force`, though `Force` is also passed in:

```
function myls($Exclude) {
    # only Exclude is in $PSBoundParameters even though we send Force, too:
    $PSBoundParameters | Out-String | Out-Host
    Write-Output "hello!"
    Get-ChildItem @PSBoundParameters
}
cd d
myls -Exclude b -Force
```

Option 2. In theory in should be possible to build a hashtable from the array `$args` manually and apply the splat operator to it. But this task does not look practically attractive.

---

**UPDATE**

Well, there is actually yet another ad-hoc option (pure hack!) that requires minimum effort and will work in some trivial, mostly interactive, scenarios. It is not for somehow serious code!

```
function myls {
    # extra job
    Write-Output "hello!"

    # invoke/repeat the calling code line with myls "replaced" with Get-ChildItem
    Set-Alias myls Get-ChildItem
    Invoke-Expression $MyInvocation.Line
}

cd d

# variables can be used as the parameter values, too
$exclude = 'b'

myls -Exclude $exclude -Force
```

Comment: The hack works and it has the advantage that one doesn't need to handle (or even know about) all the various optional parameters.

Comment: Well, it works but not well enough for real use. `$MyInvocation.Line` is the whole calling line including other statements, too. As a result, this doesn't work: `$result = myls ...`. But this seems to work: `myls ... -OutVariable result`.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that too.  There must be a fix.  I'll let you know if I find one.

Comment: I found another solution: `Invoke-Expression ("Get-ChildItem " + $MyInvocation.UnboundArguments -join " ")` Also it doesn't require the alias hack.  It doesn't handle param values (e.g., `myls -Exclude $exclude -Force`) though.

Comment: I think `$MyInvocation.UnboundArguments` is the same as `$args` or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this:

function myls { Write-Output "hello!"; iex "Get-ChildItem @args"}

will come closer to producing the expected result.

Update:  There is apparently a known bug with using @args in this manner to pass named parameters:

https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/368512/splat-operator-args-doesnt-properly-pass-named-arguments?wa=wsignin1.0

I'd discontinue using that until it's resolved.

Comment: It's closer -- it doesn't produce an error -- unfortunately it also ignores the args.  If you try the test above, the outputs of `myls` and `myls -Exclude b` are, incorrectly, the same.

Comment: Try it without that first line.